# Chrome Extension: why I can't pass variable to function (JS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new at JavaScript.
I am working on Chrome Extension now.

I need to parse project name from page (Vtiger CRM), then create Card in Trello, name of the card must be the parsed project name. (sorry for my English).

manifest.json

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Roonyx VTIGER optimizer",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Создание доски в Trello и чата в Discord",
    "icons": {
        "64": "icon.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Roonyx VTIGER optimizer",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "settings/index.html",
        "popup.html"
    ],
    "options_page": "settings/index.html",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js",
                "scripts/client.js",
                "scripts/key.js",
                "scripts/settings.js",
                "scripts/hashSearch.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": ["storage", "identity", "tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

Here is part of my background.js code:

```
var myProject;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      window.myProject = $(request.content).find(".projectname").text(); 
    });

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: "chrome.extension.sendMessage({content: document.body.innerHTML}, function(response) { console.log('success'); });"
    }, function() { console.log('done'); });
});

// Trello Creating Card

var APP_KEY = '*app_key*';
var myList = '5d1089c67893fe7afb014694';

function trelloInit() {
    Trello.setKey(APP_KEY);
    Trello.setToken(localStorage.getItem('trello_token'));
}

var creationSuccess = function (data) {
    console.log('Card created successfully.');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    console.log(myProject);
};

var newCard = {
    name: myProject, 
    desc: 'This is the description of our new card.',
    // Place this card at the top of our list 
    idList: myList,
    pos: 'top'
};

function createCard() {
    $("#trello_create_card").click(function () {
        trelloInit();
        Trello.post('/cards/', newCard, creationSuccess);     
    });
}

$(document).ready(createCard);
```

I see needed project name in console as expected, when script executes "console.log(myProject)" in creationSuccess function.

But I see created card with blank name in Trello.
I have already tried to use window.myProject in newCard, but nothing changes...

If you need to see the entire setup, you can see repo at GitHub:
https://github.com/AnatolySt/chrome-roonyx

Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong please?
Thank you in advance)

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page so the fragment of code in the question doesn't make a lot of sense to me as I don't see the entire setup. Try presenting the info in a way that makes it possible for us to understand the workflow, also include manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm https://github.com/AnatolySt/chrome-roonyx

Comment: Based on the [incomplete] info in the question I can see you're assuming the message is received synchronously which is not how the API works. Your onMessage listener/callback is invoked at some later time after the outside parts of script have already completed. See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: I have added manifest.json to my post. I'm reading post from your link, thanks